# Swift Compile Error: Unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using SpriteKit and Swift on my game. But when I want compile my project, get unresolved identifier. But everything seems good.

```
    var sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path!, options:DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
```

Problem:

```
Swift Compile Error: Use of unresolved identifier: 'wDataReadingMappedIfSafe'
```

How can I fix it? What's my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 errors:

- `DataReadingMappedIfSafe` should be `.DataReadingMappedIfSafe` with the leading dot
  for an enumeration value.
- `NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(...)` is not available in Swift anymore, you have to
  use `NSData(contentsOfFile: ...)`

Together:

```
var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!, options:.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
```